# Sed Regex to delete all numbers except ordinals

Tags: regex, perl, sed, regex-lookarounds

I need to delete all numbers from a file except those followed by (ST|TH|[RN]D) (ordinal numbers). I'm not sure how to introduce an exception into sed like that (I know of [^] but that wouldn't let me give the string optional (ST|TH|[RN]D).

It seems that lookaheads might be the answer but my construction isn't working

```
s/[0-9][0-9]*(?!(ST|[RN]D))//g
```

Sample input:

```
12663 METRO CONDOMINIUM AS DESC IN INST# 200800031138 UNIT A
126TH AVENUE INDUSTRIAL PARK
13 AND 12-29-19
102-1st AVE CONDO
```

Just added the last one, and that is a doozy of input. I would really like to eliminate the preceding numbers but leave the ordinal. Revo's example worked pretty well. But this edge case is actually important to me.

Expected output:

```
METRO CONDOMINIUM AS DESC IN INST#  UNIT A
126TH AVENUE INDUSTRIAL PARK
 AND --
-1st AVE CONDO
```

Don't care about eliminating spaces. Can do that on my own.

Comment: Sed does not support look-arounds, which are a PCRE construct (Perl compatible regular expressions); sed only supports Basic and Extended regular expressions.

Comment: What tool might I use instead? Will the stated regex work?

Comment: Could you add example input? Are the numbers on separate lines, or within text? As for tools, Perl comes to mind.

Comment: What would you like to output to be?

Comment: Please add expected output.

Comment: @malan - Perl would work.  Perl is pretty good at one-liners: `perl -pe 's/[0-9][0-9]*(?!(ST|[RN]D))//g;'`.  Sadly, given the question's tags, perl may be out of scope.

Comment: @Mr.Llama You need to add `[0-9]` to the lookahead. Otherwise it'll match `12` in `123RD`.

Comment: I don't know perl. but if it works, I wouldn't be opposed to using it and will modify tags and accept your answer. Also, I forgot an ordinal in my (ST|[RN]D): TH

Comment: `12-29-19` is not a number. Why does your expected output show it as removed?

Comment: Good point. Not a problem either. I can remove punctuation on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since sed doesn't have support for lookarounds you have to define each path using:

```
[0-9]+(([sS]([^Tt]|$)|[Tt]([^Hh]|$)|[RNrn]([^Dd]|$))|[^RNSTrnst0-9]|$)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/lhkVPp/1)

For case-insensitivity I included both upper and lower cases into bracket notations.

GNU sed command (POSIX ERE):

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]+(([sS]([^Tt]|$)|[Tt]([^Hh]|$)|[RNrn]([^Dd]|$))|[^RNSTrnst0-9]|$)/\1/g' file
```

Regex breakdown:

```
[0-9]+ # Match digits
( # Start of Capturing Group #1
    ( # Start of Capturing Group #2
        [sS] # Match S or s
        ( # Start of Capturing Group #3
            [^Tt] # If a character exists after S it shouldn't be T
            | # Or
            $ # Match end of line position
        ) # End of Capturing Group #3
        | # Or 
        [RNrn] # Match a letter from set
        ( # Start of Capturing Group #4
            [^Dd] # If a character exists after R or N it shouldn't be D
            | # Or
            $ # Match end of line position
        ) # End of Capturing Group #4
    ) # End of Capturing Group #2
    | # Or
    [^RNSrns0-9] # Match a letter from other than one in set
    | # Or
    $ # Match end of line position
) # End of Capturing Group #1
```

Comment: This is a very confusing regex. Could you explain it slightly more? The dollar signs and [^T] and [^D] are throwing me. Also, needs support for ordinal 'TH'.

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to add a breakdown.

Comment: Thank you Revo. I am going to accept your answer, but could you please add support for ordinal 'TH' as in '4TH'. I initially forgot it in my question but have added it.

Comment: I won't go adding that into original version. So lazy I'm but here it is `[0-9][0-9]*(([sS]([^Tt]|$)|[Tt]([^Hh]|$)|[RNrn]([^Dd]|$))|[^RNSTrnst]|$)`

Comment: Revo, it ended up failing on multiple number examples of the form 102ND AVENUE PARK. I'm gonna switch the answer to the perl script. I guess our sed partisanship didn't pay off after all.

Comment: @malan You acted so quick without waiting for an answer. Anyhow, that was a mistake of not excluding numbers within `[^RNSTrnst]` set. You may want to play with live demo now.

Comment: I can't imagine how the OP is looking at that regexp compared to the regexps in the other answers and thinking "yup, that's exactly the way I want my code to look!" but in any case - you should mention that solution is GNU sed only for `-r`.

Comment: @EdMorton Programming isn't simple, regular expressions are no exception. Hence I wrote those comments on each pattern to explain which does what. I didn't write them for fun. And for gnu sed part, I mentioned by parenthesizing *POSIX ERE*.  At the time I was writing this answer `perl` tag wasn't added to the post otherwise I'd have chose it. This answer is valid, right and provides helpful information. I got a downvote just after your comment. Weird.

Comment: I did not downvote you or I'd have left a comment stating why. I certainly wouldn't downvote just because you didn't state the answer was GNU-only and the OP did ask for a sed solution so I can't fault you for providing one. You may notice my comment got an upvote so maybe the 2 things are related, idk. Yes, you're using a POSIX ERE but your answer requires GNU sed to execute it so I'm just stating the obvious that you should state that GNU sed is required so future readers don't waste their time trying it with non-GNU seds.

Comment: @EdMorton Can we use ERE version with POSIX sed?! Anyhow, I updated to clearly state it.

Comment: Best I can tell all you'd have to do for that to work with any POSIX sed is escape every (, ), and |. You could also replace `-r` with `-E` and then it'd work with 2 seds - GNU (newer versions) and OSX.

Answer (score 2):

Sed doesn't support look-ahead, but Perl does. However, your regex isn't quite right: In `123RD` it matches `12` (because `12` is a sequence of digit that's not followed by `ST` or `ND` or `RD`; it's followed by `3`).

You can fix this by adding adding `[0-9]` to the look-ahead:

```
perl -pe 's/[0-9][0-9]*(?!([0-9]|ST|[RN]D))//g'
```

Also, you don't need the inner capturing parens in the look-ahead group, `XX*` can be simplified to `X+`, and we want to exclude `TH` as well:

```
perl -pe 's/[0-9]+(?![0-9]|ST|[RN]D|TH)//g'
```

Sample output from your test input:

```
 METRO CONDOMINIUM AS DESC IN INST#  UNIT A
126TH AVENUE INDUSTRIAL PARK
 AND --
-st AVE CONDO
```

Note that the `1` in `1st` was removed. This is because `S` does not match `s`. We can fix that by making the regex case insensitive:

```
perl -pe 's/[0-9]+(?![0-9]|ST|[RN]D|TH)//ig' test.txt
```

```
 METRO CONDOMINIUM AS DESC IN INST#  UNIT A
126TH AVENUE INDUSTRIAL PARK
 AND --
-1st AVE CONDO
```

Comment: Just use a non-backtracking quantifier: `s/ \d++ (?!ST|TH|[RN]D) /igx`

Comment: @Borodin That also works, but I prefer to write backtracking-agnostic regexes where possible (i.e. regexes that work the same way whether quantifiers are greedy, non-greedy, or possessive) and in this case it's easily possible. Also, your code has two bugs: 1. Typo: You're missing a `/`. 2. `\d` matches more than just `[0-9]`; it matches all Unicode digit characters. You need `/a` to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will get you most of the way there: a sequence of digits not followed by an alphanumeric character or end-of-line

```
$ cat file
foo 1234 bar 32nd gaz 1234
1234hello

$ sed -E 's/[[:digit:]]+($|[^[:alnum:]])/\1/g' file
foo  bar 32nd gaz 
1234hello
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines (e.g. `s/old/new/`), that is all. For anything else you should be using awk. With GNU awk for multi-char RS, RT, and IGNORECASE:

```
$ awk -v RS='[0-9]+(ST|TH|[RN]D)' -v IGNORECASE=1 '{gsub(/[0-9]+/,""); ORS=RT} 1' file
 METRO CONDOMINIUM AS DESC IN INST#  UNIT A
126TH AVENUE INDUSTRIAL PARK
 AND --
-1st AVE CONDO
```

Comment: sed and awk should have been outmoded decades ago when Perl arrived. It is capable of everything that the older utilities can do plus much more `perl -pe 's/ \d++ (?!ST|TH|[RN]D) /igx' myfile` does the trick.

Comment: @Borodin absolutely right. I wonder why that didn't happen? http://www.zoitz.com/archives/13 :-).

Comment: @EdMorton: Hehe the old "write-only" insult! Perl's a lot easier to read than the equivalent awk or sed unless you try really hard to obfuscate it. Compare my code to yours! I think the old languages hang on partly because of inertia and partly because Perl is seen more as a programming language than a command-line utility.

Comment: If perl were a lot easier to read than awk then there wouldn't BE `the old "write-only" insult`. Not that I actually care though, I'm sure perl must have its uses or it wouldn't still be hanging around after all these years. I tried it and you have a bug in your code btw - `Substitution replacement not terminated at -e line 1.`.

Comment: @EdMorton Well, if people actually learned Perl and wrote good code in it (instead of being afraid of it and vomiting out horrible code), then the world might be a better place. Case in point: The code in the comic you linked to  (`s/:/g`) has the same bug: There's a missing `/` in the replacement part.

Comment: I think it's the sigils that upset people, which are essentially built-in Hungarian notation: it makes Perl code unusually rich with non-alphanumerics. Sorry about the error; I don't have a command prompt to hand to test stuff. There's a slash missing and the substitution should end with `...//igx`.

Comment: @revo: I'm glad you enjoyed it! But seriously, isn't it odd that sed and awk remain popular when Perl is a superset of both of them? Moreover, they (and shell) have the same problem with multiple symbolic characters that Perl does.

Comment: @Borodin Very late to comment. No... it's not odd, seriously. I never choose a tab to read my pdf files while an e-book reader exists. awk / sed is the ASIC-tool here.

Comment: @revo: I didn't realise there was a deadline; sorry! *"I never choose a tab"* do you mean a browser tab? I don't think reading PDF files can be compared to a choice of command-line tools. A similar anomaly exists with awk, which can replace sed in most situations. I'm sure ASIC users would have gladly used BASIC if it were available.

Comment: @Borodin No, I mean a tablet computer.

Comment: @revo: You'd really pick up a Kindle in preference to an Android tablet with a Kindle app? I can't relate to that at all. Perhaps that's why I can't understand people's preference for awk over Perl!

Comment: @Borodin Yes. Is that weird or something? The point is easy to get I'm not sure why you complicate it.

Comment: @revo: I think it is you who are complicating things by having a different tool for every circumstance. Do you also have a separate compass, camera, and diary to reduce the complication?

Comment: @Borodin wrt why perl hasn't replaced awk and why it gets a bad reputation for it's syntax, see the perl answer just posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50566802/1745001 compared to the clear, simple awk solutions on the same page. I know you can't generalize from a single answer but that, to me, **is** absolutely typical of perl answers - just a mush of cryptic symbols in random combinations. I'm sure it could be written clearly and simply in perl too but it almost never is because perl allows you to write briefer code so people do that despite the result being incomprehensible.

Comment: @EdMorton: I agree that that example is disgraceful, and has presumably been upvoted by people who find such hackery to be clever. I don't think you'll find many examples of such poor coding, and it wouldn't stand a chance of passing a decent code review. However, the only awk I find readable is your own answer; the others are mostly opaque to me, not helped by the pervasive use of single-character identifiers which seems obligatory in most awk code. If you fairly compare Perl solutions to awk or sed, I think you will find that the former are more legible.

Comment: This debate did nothing to solve a question spawned from this thread: should I learn perl or awk to handle my basic cli text-processing needs? (I have the sed & awk book ([sed&awk](https://www.amazon.com/sed-awk-Dale-Dougherty/dp/1565922255)) from o'reilly but only read the sed chapters. I have never wanted to learn perl b/c of the issue debated here. But melpomene's answer made me think it would be easier than awk and sed combined. Can I just learn basic perl to handle sed/awk type tasks? Why can't Python handle the same things as easily as perl did in melpomene's example?)

Comment: malan you never use awk+sed combined, and you don't need a book to learn what sed is for (s/old/new/). I totally disagree with @Borodins claim that perl scripts are more legible than awk scripts, my personally experience is that awk scripts are always clearer. I do agree with him that sed scripts to do more than s/old/new/ are more incomprehensible than perl scripts but you should not be using sed for that. Python or Ruby can handle the same things. The difference from the others is that only awk is available as standard on all UNIX systems, and has a tiny language JUST for text processing.

Answer (score 0):

With sed and your input file

```
sed -E 's/(\<[0-9]+\>)//g' infile
```

**output**

```
 METRO CONDOMINIUM AS DESC IN INST#  UNIT A
126TH AVENUE INDUSTRIAL PARK
 AND --
-1st AVE CONDO
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/^/\n/;:a;s/\n([^0-9]+)/\1\n/;ta;s/\n([0-9]*(1st|2nd|3rd|[4-90]th))/\1\n/I;ta;s/\n[0-9]+/\n/;ta;s/\n//' file
```

Use a newline as a delimiter to parse each line. Insert a newline at the head of the line. If the string following the newline is not numeric, pass over that string. If the string following the newline is ordinal, also pass over the string. If the string following the newline is numeric, remove it. At the end of the line, remove the newline delimiter.